# Change fixed text at certain points of a page

Tags: html, css, text, scroll

I'm hoping someone can help me solve a functionality I'm having trouble achieving.

Here's the scenario: I have a long page that has four sections. When I load this page, there is a fixed text in the middle of the page that says "one". Upon scrolling down to the second section, the fixed text fades from "one" to "two". "two" fades to "three" when scrolling down to the third section; so on and so forth.

Is this type of functionality possible? I'm assuming it involves jquery and css.

Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

Actually this can now be accomplished using CSS only solution with `position: sticky` depending on your layout. Check [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) on more how it works, there you also have codepen example which is pretty much similar to your use case.

Based on your example here is the working code.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div>
        <div class="heading">One</div>
        <div class="content">
            content
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="heading">two</div>
        <div class="content">
            content
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="heading">three</div>
        <div class="content">
            content
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="heading">Four</div>
        <div class="content">
            content
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.heading {
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    font-size: 30px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0px;
}

.content {
    height: 300px;
    background: green;
}
```

Note that you needed to wrap sticky element into another div so he knows when is obsolete and needs to remove itself from viewport.

Comment: Hey Mario, thanks for commenting. I did give it a go, but I can't seem to get the sticky div at a fixed position and get the text to replace one another. Any idea on how I can make this work? jsfiddle.net/kenhimself/pfc9zmz5/1/